# Keyboard input lags on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, 17.10

I have recently updated my Ubuntu to 17.10. After the upgrade, my keyboard is acting strange. If I select my default keyboard layout (Portuguese Brazil), for every key I type in, the active window freezes for 4 to 6 seconds, and afterwards the typed character is shown. The same issue happens If I have portuguese (Brazil) on my keyboard layout list, even if it's not activated.

If I set the input layout to English (US) and remove everything else, it works, but nos as smoothly as it should be. I still can see some delays between key presses, and it`s kinda annoying use a keyboard layout different from my regional one.

I've also tested with an external USB keyboard (with US layout), and the issue persists.

My current configuration is:

```
System:    Kernel: 4.13.0-16-generic x86_64 bits: 64
           Desktop: Gnome 3.26.1 Distro: Ubuntu 17.10
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Avell High Performance product: 1513
           Mobo: N/A model: N/A serial: N/A
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: N.1.00 date: 12/27/2016
Battery    BAT0: charge: 44.3 Wh 100.0% condition: 44.3/47.5 Wh (93%)
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-7300HQ (-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           clock speeds: max: 3500 MHz 1: 2500 MHz 2: 2500 MHz 3: 2500 MHz
           4: 2500 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Device 591b
           Card-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.19.5 ) drivers: modesetting,nvidia
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1050/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 384.90
Audio:     Card Intel Device a171 driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.13.0-16-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIE Gigabit Ethernet
           driver: r8169
           IF: enp2s0 state: up speed: 100 Mbps duplex: full
           mac: b0:25:aa:1f:c7:db
           Card-2: Intel Wireless 8265 / 8275 driver: iwlwifi
           IF: wlp3s0 state: down mac: 00:28:f8:0f:80:39
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 2165.5GB (3.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: TOSHIBA_MQ02ABD1 size: 1000.2GB
           ID-2: /dev/sdb model: Crucial_CT525MX3 size: 525.1GB
           ID-3: USB /dev/sdc model: S2_Portable size: 640.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 916G used: 6.4G (1%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 61.5C mobo: N/A gpu: 43C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 205 Uptime: 26 min Memory: 1725.6/15965.0MB
           Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.37
```

---

Is there anything ele I should test before reporting the issue? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem some days ago. Someone told me in private that you have the ^@ character printed every second on tty. That's a known bug in the peaq-wmi driver. Blacklist it and reboot.

Comment: I was about to close the thread because I did exactly that haha! Thanks :)

Comment: I am having this problem. How does one exactly disable the driver??

Comment: Depends on your system. In my system I created the file `/etc/modprobe.d/nowmi.conf` with the contents `blacklist peaq-wmi`