# Volume and brighness adjustment OSD delay and screen freeze on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, gnome-shell, notify-osd

Every time I raise/lower the volume, or change screen brightness through the keyboard, the screen freezes for 1 to 2 seconds before the corresponding OSD appears and shows the change. It didn't happen on 16.04 - started on 18.04.

If I do the same command in the next couple seconds the freeze doesn't happen (the OSD is fast as it should be).

My computer is new (16G RAM, i7-8750H, nVIDIA GTX 1050ti). The problem happens exclusively on Gnome Shell + Xorg combination - if using cinnamon or Gnome Shell + Wayland it works as expected (but both options have their downsides too, so I prefer to stick with Gnome shell). Any ideas of why this is happening? It gets pretty annoying over time :(

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer to this other question of mine https://askubuntu.com/a/1163929/834984 also solved this problem.

Copied below the relevant part of the answer:
*"After some digging i found out the culprit is the ScrollLock key and that can be fixed by editing the layout file, which in my case is found at /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br. The only modification i did was to remove or comment the line: modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock }; After that, set the language and layout back to Portugues (Brasil) and the problem was gone!"*

Thank you [Gustavo Silva](https://askubuntu.com/users/982738/gustavo-silva)

Comment: This problem still is up on ubuntu 20! I hope that canonical fix it, it makes an bad experience.

Comment: I noticed that after some time, the problem is back. The modification i manually did was undone, doing it again fixed it. Do you know why it reversed back to original?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the line

```
modifier_map Mod3 { Scroll_Lock };
```

at `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br` only worked for me after deleting the US keyboard input and adding it again, not just switching between them.

Now there still seems to be a delay, but it is very small and acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following command and it will fix:

```
sudo sed -i '/modifier_map Mod3   { Scroll_Lock }\;/ s/^\/*/\/\//' /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/br
```