# Random freezing on typing or opening softwares // High speed and noisy CPU FAN on Linux distros

Tags: dual-boot, fan, temperature, 20.04, amd-ryzen

I recently buy a new machine with the following config:

- Ryzen 5 3600x
- ASROCK A320m-HD. (with lastest bios update)
- 16gb RAM DDR4
- NVIDIA GTX 1660

I installed windows 10, all fine, cool temps and stuff, but when i tried linux (with ubuntu dual boot 18.04 LTS mostly) my cpu fan speed spikes up randomly and i have a noisy annoying sound all the time...

Also, on ubuntu i have a delay/freeze when i type text, like typing this message right now.

I've tried other distros like linux mint and there is no typing delay, only the noisy fan...

I'm new to linux world and I have no clue what to do... I appreciate any help

```
fool@fool-desktop:~$ sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tdie:         +51.4°C  (high = +70.0°C)
Tctl:         +51.4°C
```

other

```
fool@fool-desktop:~$ ps aux | grep -i therm
root         212  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        I<   16:34   0:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
fool       10071  0.0  0.0  17684  2768 pts/0    S+   16:51   0:00 grep --color=auto -i therm
```

on Vitals with normal browsing:

```
60ºC
Voltage: No data
CPU FAN: No data
Memory: 12%
CPU: 0%
```

free -h

```
fool@fool-desktop:~$ free -h
              total       used          free      shared  buff/cache  disponível
Mem.:          15Gi       1,6Gi        12Gi        97Mi       1,5Gi        13Gi
Swap:         1,4Gi          0B       1,4Gi
```

.

```
fool@fool-desktop:~$ sysctl vm.swappiness
vm.swappiness = 60
```

Comment: Install something like `lm-sensors`, or the `Vitals` GNOME Shell extension, and check your temps. Report back.

Comment: added to the post

Comment: It's funny that `sensors` doesn't show your CPU temps, Try `Vitals`.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ps auxc | grep -i therm`.

Comment: Done... this freeze while typing is killing me rn

Comment: Is it freezing? You didn't mention that. Show me `free -h` and `sysctl vm.swappiness`.

Comment: I used the word "delay" on the original post. My bad. Done

Comment: I would Google "ryzen ubuntu" or "ryzen linux" and see what you get. Some time ago they found a problem with early ryzen processors running on linux. They ended up swapping the processors under warranty. There may also be some kernel mods that need to be made in /etc/default/grub to make this work. Also, although I don't think this is your current problem, your swap is kind of low... I'd recommend a 4G /swapfile.

Comment: I'll search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the temp/and the noisy fan by disabling `Core Performance Boost` in my bios;

```
 1. BIOS "Advanced"; 
 2. AMD CBS;  
 3. Core Performance Boost > DISABLED;
 4. F10
 5. SAVE;
```

The freeze/lag while typing was an error with the keyboard layout I was using (ABNT2).
I followed this tutorial [Ubuntu 18.04 input slow when Portuguese (Brazil) layout among keyboard input sources](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041335/ubuntu-18-04-input-slow-when-portuguese-brazil-layout-among-keyboard-input-sou)