# Keyboard typing delay

Tags: ubuntu-studio

For some reason when i am typing it doesn't always show the text on the screen. At other times it will just delay it. Then there's times it types fine. I did a fresh install of Ubuntu Studio 2-3 days ago and its only today this started happening. Sorry whoever gives me suggestions can you fill me in every step of it. I am not super good with linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keyboard input lags on ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968788/keyboard-input-lags-on-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: Hi if i can have a lot my detail. I dont know how to create that file. I need every step as i am not that good with linux yet